# Is there a Rules Condition for 'is user:' or 'is root user'?

Tags: 7, users, rules

I am creating a rule that will help to manage permissions, but I only want it to run for the user with `uid=1`.

Is there a way to add a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Condition based on user data? Is such a condition prone to problems, and should I instead need to create a new permission?

Comment: There's only one root user, and it always has ID: 1...

Comment: I can reference the uid as a field?   I did not think of that.

Comment: Yes exactly, you can just do a simple data comparison against user:uid

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is such [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Condition. As an example, have a look at the Rule I included in my answer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to admins, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)".

The Rules Condition included that answer performs a Data Comparison to check if the value of `site:current-user:uid` is not equal to `1` (in your case you'd want to check if it is equal to `1`).

**Note**: This specific Rules Condition comes in handy for anything you want to enforce (or prohibit?) for super user user/1 (which typically skips all permissions), similar to what the question was about in the linked question here.