# Displaying a Block on 2nd level pages but not 3rd level

Tags: blocks

I have a block that I would like to only display on documents/* but not on /documents/*/*.

I have set 'Show block on specific pages - only the listed pages' 'documents/*' but this displays the block on all children of documents.

How do I set it to only display on documents/company (etc) and not documents/company/board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drupal.org/project/context module can do this. In addition to the typical wildcard `*` operator ... its Path conditions support a Not operator `~`.

Comment: Tried ~documents/*/*. How do path conditions work?

Comment: You prompted me to try 'all pages except those listed' and 2 rules - documents/*/*  plus */ seems to work.

Comment: documents/*
~documents/*/*

Comment: OK - the ~ negation isn't available in the standard block configuration. It needs context.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in page.tpl.php

put this code their

```
if(arg(1)=='documents' && !isset(arg(3)==''))
{
//render block here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If PHP filter is enabled you can use this in "Show block on specific pages - PHP"

```
$whitelist = "documents/*";
$blacklist = "documents/*/*";
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
if (drupal_match_path($path, $whitelist) && !drupal_match_path($path, $blacklist)) {
   return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this question is about D7, there is another alternative to answer it: use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) "***check the path of the current page***" (so that the block is only shown on your pages with a path that **starts with** "`documents/`", but not on those pages that have a path like "`documents/*/*`").

For an illustration of how to use this module, refer to my answer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to administrators, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)". It includes a Rules Component (in Rules export format), which you should replace by this variation of it to make it match your specific question):

```
{ "rules_block_visibility_show_on_selected_profile_pages" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show block on selected profile pages",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "module" : { "label" : "Module", "type" : "text" },
      "delta" : { "label" : "Delta", "type" : "text" },
      "result" : { "label" : "Result", "type" : "boolean", "parameter" : false }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "AND" : [
          { "text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "documents\/",
              "operation" : "starts"
            }
          },
          { "NOT text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "documents(\/[a-z]*)?(\/)?$/",
              "operation" : "regex"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "result" ]
  }
}
```

**Note**: the 2nd Rules Condition in the above Rules Component (with the regular expression in it) may need further refinements to perfectly fit your case. I.e. the "`documents(\/[a-z]*)?(\/)?$/`" part of it (though I think it's pretty close to what your question is about).