# How to display blocks depending on the logged in user?

Tags: blocks

How can I display blocks depending on the logged in user?

Let's say I have a Block1 and Block2. When user1 is logged in, that user should only see Block1, but user2 should only see Block2

I found the [Logic Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/logic_block) module, but it doesn't seem to work *for what I'm trying to do*.

Comment: First, why by users? Can't you do it by role? Second thing, " it doesn't work" is most useless report in IT :) Tell us what you did, what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: Try to control it with User Roles.

Comment: Ow, I'm sorry, :D I would try user roles. By it doesn't work I mean't. I tried the to set everything and followed the instructions. But still nothing happens.

Comment: "Nothing happens" == no blocks shown? Or all blocks shown, no matter who is looking? Or [tag:wsod]? There are many ways nothing can happen ;)

Comment: worth checking it https://www.drupal.org/project/block_access

Comment: Have a look at [my answer to this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173) ... Which explains how to do so for "user/1" (like your user1) ... And use a similar approach to do the same for "user/X"(like your user2). It's that easy.

Answer (score 3):

You could go to blocks setting and there are Roles tab.
If you check "anonymous user" - this block will visible only for not loggined user. If you check " authenticated user" - block will be visible loggined user.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module. There you can compare current user id, user role etc to show blocks.