# How do I make block only visible if the 'field_date_value' is in the past?

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

What code do I use on a D7 website if I want a block only to be visible if the `field_date_value` of a date node is in the past?

On a D6 site, I had this working for all date nodes:

```
$match = FALSE;
$types = array('date' => 1);
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1) )) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid));
  $type = $node->type;
  if (isset($types[$type])) {
    $match = TRUE;
  }
}
return $match;
```

But this code does not work on a D7 site. Besides, all that I want is it to only show a date node when the date in the past. (For a past event.)

Answer (score 0):

Pretend you need a block to be visible on a node depending on the value of a date field on the node.

A good example is a website that lists classes as nodes. You want a block visible only on class nodes. You also only want that block visible if the date of the class is in the future.

The classes are created by making nodes of a custom content type called "class". Each class node contains an date field called "class_date" that contains the date of the first day of the class. The date field is a regular ISO date field type. This PHP snippet returns TRUE if the node is a "class" and the "class_date" field is in the future and the block is then visible.

```
<?php
$node = menu_get_object();
if ( !empty($node)  && $node->type == 'class' ) {
  if ( !empty($node->field_class_date) && !empty($node->field_class_date['und']) && !empty($node->field_class_date['und'][0]) ) {
     $parts = explode('T', $node->field_class_date['und'][0]['value']);
     $date_parts =  explode('-', $parts[0]);
     $class_date = $date_parts[1] . '/' . $date_parts[2] . '/' . $date_parts[0] . ' ' .  $parts[1];
     $on = strtotime($class_date);
     $now = time();
     if ( $on >= $now ) {
        return TRUE;
     }
  }
}
return FALSE;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry Pravin Ajaaz but I can get your code working. I tried by substituting class with date and that didn't do the trick.
Also editing your field_class_date with the existing field_date_value didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module instead. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) "perform validations similar to the logic included in the code shown in your question".

For an illustration of how to use this module, refer to my answer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to admins, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)".