# How to configure the default visibility to "Only the listed pages" when adding a block?

Tags: blocks

When adding a block to the site:

```
Home » Administration » Structure » Blocks
```

the default setting for visibility is set to "All pages except those listed." is there a way to set the default setting to "Only the listed pages"?

I'd guess that this possible w/ a custom module but I'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add this to you admin theme's (default is Seven) template.php file (so no custom module):

```
function seven_form_block_add_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  $form['visibility']['path']['visibility']['#default_value'] = BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED;
}
```

or if your admin theme is something else:

```
function ADMINTHEME_form_block_add_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  $form['visibility']['path']['visibility']['#default_value'] = BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED;
}
```

Refer to [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) for more info.

Comment: The exact answer I needed.  Also helps to reinforce the fundamental paradigm of Drupal:  "There a hook/module for that".

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The block add admin form is [hard-coded](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/block/block.admin.inc?h=7.43#n380) to use `BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED` (i.e. "All pages.." option) as the default option; there's no configuration setting there. The only way around this is to form alter it with a module.

Comment: hook_form_alter works in theme template files also.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless:
>
> - Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
> - Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
> - What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) "***check the path of the current page***" (so that the block is only shown for the listed pages).

For an illustration of how to use this module, refer to my answer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to admins, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)".