# Slideshow on the pages

Tags: media, views, javascript

I am looking for a method to put différents slideshows on different pages. I mean every pages must have his own slideshow. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course it is, anything is possible with Drupal `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module, for each slideshow you create, you also get a corresponding *block* that you need to position in an appropriate region.

So say you have 3 slideshows, ie ShowA, ShowB and ShowC, and you want to show them like so:

- Show A on page with node id = X.
- Show B on page with node id = Y.
- Show C on page with node id = Z.

In this case, all you need to do is to adapt the "Visibility settings" (pages) for each *block* like so:

- For the block related to ShowA, only show this block on page node/X.
- For the block related to ShowB, only show this block on page node/Y.
- For the block related to ShowC, only show this block on page node/Z.

#### Possible enhancements

Even though the above should be sufficient to answer your question, there are all sorts of enhancements to the above approach you may want to consider:

- Use a content type (eg "Slide"), to create slides that you want to be shown in a slideshow. And optionally also add an extra field to that content type to identify in which slideshow (ShowA, ShowB, etc) you want an extra slide to be shown. And/or add another field to indicate some type of sequence (like slide nr) of those slides to be shown.
- Use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module to make the visibility of the blocks more dynamic, by using some [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) logic to yes/no show a specific slideshow-block. Refer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to admins, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)" for way more details about how to use [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility).

Comment: This is similar to what our developer did; they also created a slideshow content type so that we could change the individual slides as and when we need.

Comment: @DarrenWhittenham-Gray : actually such slideshow content type is what I typically also do/use to give more flexibility to the site's content maintainers. See my updated answer for a few other possible enhancements

Comment: Thank you so much Pierre. it is very complicated to use views.

Comment: Comments have been removed. @Koçer Please don't use it for extended discussion. The user who answered the question should not be pinged to answer other related questions. If you don't understand what the user is saying in the answer, it is fine to politely ask. Don't expect the user visits your site to see what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flex Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) module you can find the configuration for module in description and you can watch [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8I0r6zEvjI) video for configuration.

Now you can create slide shows blocks using views flexslider formatter here you can find various settings for slideshow in block.

Now you can see the blocks created by views in admin > structure > blocks.

Add this blocks on different page by adding "Visibility settings" to each block in block settings. By choosing only the listed pages at "Show block on specific page" option you can type URL of page on which you want this block (slide show) to display.